# NodeJS, batch processing files, alternative to writing excessive objects/functions per file?

Tags: node.js, batch-processing, mustache

I needed to get all mustache templates directory named templates/, and compile them with hogan.

In theory, assume their names are,

file1.mustache
file2.mustache
file3.mustache

Then we get a view on each one, and save the result to an output directory named build/.

In theory the resulting names would be,

name.file1
name.file2
name.file3

Obviously async is preferable, but I am most interested in how you'd do this efficiently?  I can't believe that the only way is doing per file objects and anonymous functions.

Comment: Why not just list all the files in a directory where you keep the templates and process each one?  I guess it's not clear what you're actually asking beyond the obvious solution.  Plus what does "writing excessive objects/functions per file" mean?  Perhaps show some examples of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [fs-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise) module along with `Promise.all` to easily read, process, and write your files in parallel:

```
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

function processTemplate(filename) {
  return fsp.readFile(filename, 'utf8')
    .then((template) => hogan.compile(template))
    .then((compiledTemplate) => fsp.writeFile('path/to/compiled', compiledTemplate));
}

fsp.readdir('./templates')
  .then((files) => Promise.all(files.map(processTemplate)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Although I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "per file objects and anonymous functions".